# Google Spreadsheets updating A Scripts with Multiple Tabs

Tags: google-apps-script

I have found a few threads with how to update the script but I cant get it to work with the limit knowledge I have with Scripts

I have upto about 6 Tabs ,Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4,Sheet5,Sheet6 that I want to send emails up of but at this stage it only looks at the first sheet. Can someone let me know how to update this please

Thanks Jarrad

```
function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2);  // Fetch the range of cells B1:B1
   var subject = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for subject line from above range
   var range = sheet.getRange(1, 9);  // Fetch the range of cells I1:I1
   var numRows = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for number of emails from above range
   var startRow = 4;                  // First row of data to process
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows,9 ) // Fetch the range of cells A4:I_
   var data = dataRange.getValues();  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
   for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[1];      // Second column
      var message = row[8];           // Ninth column
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
   }
}
```

Hi Cooper 
thanks for the info but im only just starting out with scripts I want to start with the basics for now and ill work out form there. I cant picture wan you are saying I know its simple info but I cant work it out just yet.
Do I remove this line `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` and replace with. I get errors on line `var range` line. I need to see it in full to try and understand what Im looking at. Sorry for the basic question

```
var sheets=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4']
  for(var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++)



function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2);  // Fetch the range of cells B1:B1
   var subject = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for subject line from above range
   var range = sheet.getRange(1, 9);  // Fetch the range of cells I1:I1
   var numRows = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for number of emails from above range
   var startRow = 4;                  // First row of data to process
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows,9 ) // Fetch the range of cells A4:I_
   var data = dataRange.getValues();  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
   for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[1];      // Second column
      var message = row[8];           // Ninth column
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

## Complete Email Sending and Archiving Example

Here's a complete example I just did recently.  I thought it was time for me to learn a little about sending emails from a spreadsheet since we get questions like this a lot. Now in your case you want to do for different sheets so I added a parameter to my sendingMyEmails() function.  So that now it's sendingMyEmails(sheetname).  You have to add either separate function calls for each sheet like below:

```
function sendEmailsSheet1()
{
   sendingMyEmails('Sheet1');
}
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
function sendAllSheets()
{
  var sheets=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4']
  for(var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++)
  {
     sendMyEmails(sheets[i]);
  }
}
```

Either way you only need one function for sending all of the emails in each sheet.  This example also includes the capability to archive your emails to an emailSent tab.  I collect all that information and then display it as an HTML Dialog which allows you to check off which emails you wish to have archived.

#### SendingEmails.gs

```
function sendingMyEmails(sheetname) 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var rng=sht.getDataRange();
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    var s='<html><head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>';
    var someNotSent=false;
    for(var i=2;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      var dataA={};
      for(var j=0;j<rngA[1].length;j++)
      {
        dataA[rngA[1][j]]=rngA[i][j];
      }
      if(dataA.EntryDate && dataA.Name && dataA.Email && dataA.Subject && dataA.Body && dataA.SendIfYes=='Yes' && dataA.DateSent=='')
      {
        MailApp.sendEmail(dataA.Email, dataA.Subject, dataA.Body, {replyTo:dataA.Sender});
        sht.getRange(i+1,8).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-6', "M/dd/yyyy'\n'HH:mm:ss"));
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
      else
      {
        var row=Number(i+1);
        s+='<div  id="row' + row + '"><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="' + Number(i+1) + '" />' + 'Email Not Sent: <strong>Row:</strong> ' + Number(i+1) + ' <strong>Name:</strong> ' + dataA.Name + ' <strong>Email:</strong> ' + dataA.Email + ' <strong>Subject:</strong> ' + dataA.Subject + ' <strong>EntryDate:</strong> ' + dataA.EntryDate + '</div>';
        someNotSent=true;
      }
    }
    if(someNotSent)
    {
      s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /><input type="button" value="Archive Checked" onClick="getCheckedBoxes(\'email\');" />';
      s+='</body></html>';
      var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlToBody').setWidth(800).setHeight(250);
      html.append(s);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Emails Not Sent');
    }
}

function archiveSelectedEmails()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('EmailSetup');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var s='<html><head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>';
  var s='';
  for(var i=2;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    var dataA={};
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[1].length;j++)
    {
      dataA[rngA[1][j]]=rngA[i][j];
    }
    var row=Number(i+1);
    s+='<div id="row' + row + '"><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="' + Number(i+1) + '" />' + ' <strong>Row:</strong> ' + Number(i+1) + ' <strong>Name:</strong> ' + dataA.Name + ' <strong>Email:</strong> ' + dataA.Email + ' <strong>Subject:</strong> ' + dataA.Subject + ' <strong>DateSent:</strong> ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dataA.DateSent), 'GMT-6', "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + '</div>';
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /><input type="button" value="Archive Checked" onClick="getCheckedBoxes(\'email\');" />';

  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlToBody').setWidth(800).setHeight(250);
  html.append(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Select Emails to Archive');
}

function test()
{
  var rows=[3];
  archiveSelectedRows(rows);
}

function archiveSelectedRows(rows,sheetname)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var dest=ss.getSheetByName('EmailsSent');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var deleted=[];
  for(var i=rngA.length-1;i>1;i--)
  {
    if(rows.indexOf(i+1)>-1)
    {
      deleted.push(Number(i+1));
      dest.appendRow(rngA[i]);
      sht.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
  var msg='Rows Deleted = ' + deleted;
  var title='Rows Deleted';
  var timeout=10;
  return deleted;
}
```

#### Sample Sheet

This is an image of the header rows for my emailSetup sheet and the emailsSent sheet has the same columns.  I don't use a dialog to identify the emails that are already sent so that I can archive them away on another sheet.
[image]

#### htmlToBody.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
  var rowsToArchive = [];
  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) 
  {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
     {
        rowsToArchive.push(Number(checkboxes[i].value));
     }
  }
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
    .archiveSelectedRows(rowsToArchive);
}

function setResponse(a)
{
  var s='<br />Rows: ';
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    if(i>0)
    {
      s+=', ';
    }
    s+=a[i];
    var id='#row' + a[i]
    $(id).css('display','none');
  }
  s+='<br />Total: ' + a.length;
  google.script.run.displayMessage(s,'Archived Rows')
}
console.log('script here');
</script>
   </head>  
  <body>
```

#### Utility.gs

```
function displayToast(msg,title,timeoutSeconds)
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(msg, title, timeoutSeconds)
}

function displayMessage(msg,title)
{
  msg+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close()"; />';
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msg).setWidth(400).setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, title);
}
```

#### Code.gs

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Send Emails','sendingMyEmails')
  .addItem('Archive Selected Emails','archiveSelectedEmails')
  .addToUi();

}
```

Comment: Link added above

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use something like this

```
function sendEmails()
{
  var mySheets=['Telstra out of date','Optus out of date','Vodafone out of date','Drivers Licence out of date'];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  { 
    var sht=allSheets[i]; 
    if(mySheets.indexOf(sht.getName())>-1)//if you have sheets you don't want to send emails from
    {
      var rng=sht.getDataRange();
      var rngA=rng.getValues();
      var subject = rngA[0][1];//B1
      for(var j=3;j<rngA.length;j++)//start row was 4
      {
        var emailAddress = rngA[j][1];//col 2
        var message = String(rngA[3][2]) + String(rngA[j][3]);//col 3
        if(emailAddress)
        {
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
          //Logger.log('EmailAddress: ' + emailAddress + ' Subject: ' + subject + ' Message: ' + message);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper When its checking for  emails its starting on row1 not row4 I do see this but it does not seem to be working  for(var j=3;j<rngA.length;j++)//start row was 4

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet.  I'll get it to work.

Comment: Well it looks like you changed your requirements a little so I had to readjust where items were going to be found.  Also you common message idea is not working it's only available to the top row.  Any I tested it on Logger.log and it looks like it's working okay.

Comment: Hi Cooper that works a treat but with the common message its only to have the info I need in it. I need the email body to come from the hidden column I not C. I changed this row (var message = String(rngA[3][2]) + String(rngA[j][3]);//col 3) to column 9 but it still didn't work any ideas ?

Comment: I didn't see anything in column 9

Comment: HI Cooper. Yeah I have the sheet pull the name from Column A, Email column B, Individualised Messages in D an the common message in C and they all combine in column I

Comment: So now I've included your greeting in the message and I used column 10 as a time stamp and if there is something in the time stamp field then emails won't be sent again.

Comment: Hi Cooper thanks for all your help with this I really appreciate it. I tried to send the emails and it says its sent but I have received no email at all ? I deleted the dates in column 10 but still no emails.

Comment: I had  disabled the MailApp because I use the logger while testing.

Comment: Also you can't delete the Sent header because it affects the width of the DataRange in getDataRange

Comment: Hi Cooper. Its emailing now. But its not grabbing the info from column 9. I get HiCheers  The training People. And the subject line

Comment: Okay it's message comes from column 8 now.

Comment: Hi @Cooper that works a treat now, thanks heaps for all your effort.This will save me a lot of time looking over things manually . This might be a new problem which might better asked in a new thread but ill ask here  first. I want to send emails via (gmails send emails from different address) When sending from gmail it works but when I emails from the sheets it comes from the gmail account not my domain email. Is there any way to fix this ??

Comment: Okay I put the GmailApp.sendMail command in there and I set the 'from' to emailAddress for now.  But if you create a column of SendAs aliases and they have to be aliases that are already setup in your account then I can add that information into the from and it will send the emails as if they were coming from that email.  If you have multiple aliases perhaps you might use validation to set up a drop down for that column

Comment: Hi @Cooper I have added the emails via data validation drop box. The first email is setup in google but the second isnt just yet – Jarrad Hall yesterday

Comment: If it's not setup in google as a verified alias then it won't work

Comment: Hi @cooper. I have removed the drop down box out of the send as column and only have the one email setup. I get the same errors Invalid argument: Myemaill address.<?> (line 22, file "Code") from column B

Comment: I think it might be time to bring this in as another question, because I'm losing track of what's going on.  Or if you want you could hire me on an hourly basis.

Comment: Hi cooper that has fixed it. I did the same as you but I put the wrong column in that s why it didnt work for me. This is what I want it to do for now but ill think of more things on the way thanks for your help. If you want to send me your details I might take you up on that offer, Until I learn this myself :D thanks again Jarrad

Comment: Contact me through my website jimesteban.com